# Is there any way of executing a Python script from a web browser?

Tags: php, python, html, browser, execution

I have a python script which I want to execute when someone clicks on a button in an HTML/PHP web page in the browser. How can this be achieved and what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Look at `exec` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php function if you're going to use pure PHP for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use flask server for this requirement as browser can not access local file.

By using flask, You need to write Ajax call in `.js`.

Sample Ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<ButtonID>').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/<Flask URL>',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
        <DATA OBJECT>
      },
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Sample Flask function

```
@app.route('/<Flask URL>',methods=['POST'])
def result():
    try:
        <DO>
    except:
        logger.error()
        raise
    return jsonify({'data':<Python variable>})
```

You might need to import necessary modules.

Answer (score 0):

With `exec`,

```
$command = "python script_path";
exec($command,$output,$return_var);
if ($return_var) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    var_dump($error)
}
```